# How to switch to a TableView from a first View?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on my first app and I've issues on how to layout some of its logics.
Basically, what the app is supposed to do is to show a first screen when launched where user can fill in some values and press a button that opens a tableview which shows results. The first screen (view), outlets and connections are all working fine. The issue I'm having is how to leave this "home" search view and show the results to the end user on a table view. Right now, I've only 1 view with its related View Controler and this controller handles the tasks of taking user inputs and get results throughout a HTTP post request.

I need your guidance...Thx in advance

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason that this all has to happen on one screen? iOS is set up to allow for this to happen very easily and (I think) attractively by using a UINavigationController and pushing in a new view controller (could be a UITableViewController or simply a UIViewController that contains a UITableView).

If you MUST have all of this take place in one view, Swastik is correct that it will require some view acrobatics. One way to do it attractively is to use the UIView animations introduced with iOS 4.

Here's Apple's UIView documentation: [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

Specifically, check out the CLASS methods of:

1. `animateWithDuration:animations:` (with or without `completion:`)

2. `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:`

Note that these methods will require you to learn a little bit about blocks, but it's worth it and I think blocks give tremendous power!

With the methods mentioned above, you could fade out your form and fade in your tableview, or maybe just move the form off-screen while the table view flies in. The possibilities are limited only by your imagination.

Comment: But I'm not sure how I could pass on the result items to the TableView from the search view controller

Answer (score 0):

u can add a table in ur xib.Initially make it hidden, & when u need to show it unhide it & also if u want to update table's data , you can reload the data of the table.